# How to move a Tumblr blog without hurting PageRank?

Tags: seo, domains, tumblr

I have a Tumblr blog which I want to move to somewhere else. I don't want my Google visibility resetted after moving. I am thinking to do it this way;

1) I believe Tumblr allows custom domain names. I will point it to my new domain, and wait for some time for Google to see the changes.

2) I will copy all my posts to new host, but they will use different URL pattern like `category-name/post-title`

3) In my new host, I will set 301 redirects for every page that existed on old blog to correct place for them on my new blog. For example, links like `post/61879534273/title-of-the-page` will be redirected to `category-name/title-of-the-page` on new host.

4) In my domain name settings, I will point my domain name to my new host.

Would this setup work as I intended? If not, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will work.

When you [use a custom domain with tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains), tumblr issues a 301 redirect<sup>1</sup> (moved permanently) for all pages and subpages to redirect your tumblr subdomain at `example.tumblr.com/path/` to your registered domain at `example.com/path/`.

When Google has re-indexed the site to display URLs with your registered domain instead of the original tumblr domain, it's safe to migrate your site to your own server by repointing the A record in your domain records, provided that you set up redirect rules on your server first, as you describe.

<sup>1</sup> – I confirmed that tumblr issues 301 redirects by sending a GET request for a post on my tumblr subdomain, which redirects to the custom domain with a 301 status:

[image: tumblr 301 redirects]